# Cookies can not be retrieved using PHP

Tags: php, cookies

This is the command with which I set cookies:

> setcookie('username', $username,
>   strtotime('+1 months'), '/',
>   '.localdomain.com/jp/');

This is the statement with which cookie is read:

```
$user=$_COOKIE['username'];
```

Why can I not read cookies on another page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your [`setcookie()`](http://php.net/setcookie) call is wrong - you can't have a path in the domain part - it should be:

```
setcookie('username', $username, strtotime('+1 months'), '/jp/', '.localdomain.com');
```